# android studio i use valueanimator to change guideline layout percent programmatically like move it from 41% to 47% but the animation is very laggy

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, android-constraintlayout

There is a tablelayout which have two tablerows and the below row is visibility.gone by default and i if i click the button, it change to visibility.visible. i programmatically change the guideline layout percent to resize the tablelayout to make space to show the tablerow, but the animation is very laggy especially everytime i run the app and first time click the button. how can I fix it?

here is my code:

```
        mMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            final ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) mGuideline1.getLayoutParams();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mShowFlag) {
                    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.41f, 0.47f);
                    valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
                    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                        lp.guidePercent = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        mGuideline1.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    });
                    valueAnimator.start();
                    mMoreButton.setText(R.string.more_up);
                    mOperatorRow2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mShowFlag = true;
                } else {
                    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.47f, 0.41f);
                    valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
                    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                        lp.guidePercent = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        mGuideline1.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    });
                    valueAnimator.start();
                    mMoreButton.setText(R.string.more_down);
                    mOperatorRow2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mShowFlag = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

i try to change the duration but it doesnt help.